# Unable to push pandas dataframe data to google bigquery table using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am unable to push pandas dataframe data to google bigquery table am getting error
"pandas_gbq.exceptions.ConversionError: Could not convert Dataframe to Parquet"

and

"pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Could not convert '1' with type str: tried to convert int64"

I have few column datatypes as int64 , float64 in pandas dataframe so same datatypes if I tried to push to bigquery table and am getting above errors

below is the code snippets I tried

**First Snippet**

```py
table_df=table_df.applymap(str)
table_df.to_gbq(table_id,project_id,if_exists="replace")
```

**Second Snippet**

```py
client = bigquery.Client()
table_id = 'dataset.table'

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(schema=[
             bigquery.SchemaField("col1", "STRING"),
             bigquery.SchemaField("col2", "NUMERIC"),
           ])

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
            table_df, table_id, job_config=job_config
      )

job.result()
```

Comment: Can you post the data types of your original df? And, maybe more importantly, are there mixed types in some column?

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes: issue got resolved thanks

Comment: Can you share how the issue got resolved?

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes: forgive for late reply.. So I crosschecked each column datatype & tried to convert columns expected format  i.e.., `table_df['col1'].astype(str)` or `table_df['col2'].astype(int64)`

Comment: Was this error on a previously working script, @snandan? I had to wipe my venv and I am now getting parquet type errors on an existing script. So I'm wondering if this is due to newly implemented typing constraints from parquet or some other lib.

Comment: @weezilla : no the reason why above script is not working is because of column data types are not in right format

Answer (score 1):

So, I had the same error message showing up using pandas_gbq in a script that had worked previously.

When I used the same script for a different location - pandas_gbq creating a new table - it worked.

When I deleted the target table and re-ran the initial script it also worked.

I recommend trying this.

Unfortunately, I haven't figured out what the reason for this behaviour is, my guess is that if your target table has a schema already and you tinker with your script the wrong way, some assertions may fail. (I tried uploading a list data type hoping it would transform it into a record ... well it doesn't ...)

If this is indeed the issue it should be a bug (or so I believe), as the "replace" flag should ideally take care of it.

I hope you get it fixed!